# Unexpected End of JSON Document, but the document is valid

Tags: javascript, json

I am passing a JSON document to a web page as a URL parameter. I have a Javascript function that processes this document and then does various things. Up until recently it was working successfully. However, I am now getting an "Unexpected End of JSON Document" error on the following document, which, according to JSONLint, is valid.

The following was generated via a console.log call from my Javascript function that is attempting to process this document.

```
?jsonDocument={"RowId":294,"DocumentName":"487_MICHAELS_ATT.pdf","FileName":"487_MICHAELS_ATT.pdf","StorageId":"942-487_MICHAELS_ATT.pdf","DocumentTypeRowId":1,"EmployeeRowId":118,"SiteRowId":null,"UnionRowId":null,"CertificationRowId":7,"VehicleRowId":null,"Comments":"","ValidFrom":"/Date(1597085452560)/","ValidTo":"/Date(253402300799999)/","AppCustomerRowId":1,"EmployeeName":"Michaels, Smith","SiteName":null,"Union":null,"Certification":"AT&T Certified","DocumentTypeDescription":"CertificationDocument","DocumentTypeInternalId":"Certification Doc","VehicleNumber":0,"VehicleInformation":null,"ContentType":"application/pdf","LastModifiedBy":"zelske@company.com","LastModifiedTime":"/Date(1597085452498)/","AssociatedWith":"CertificationDocument / Michaels, Cody / AT&T Certified"}:326
```

In my Javascrpt function I'm basically doing something like this:

```
var jsonDocument = urlParameter("document");
documentEntity = JSON.parse(jsonDocument);
```

My web page URL looks like this:

```
https://localhost:44326/Document/EditDocument/?document={%22RowId%22:294,%22DocumentName%22:%22487_MICHAELS_ATT.pdf%22,%22FileName%22:%22487_MICHAELS_ATT.pdf%22,%22StorageId%22:%22942-487_MICHAELS_ATT.pdf%22,%22DocumentTypeRowId%22:1,%22EmployeeRowId%22:118,%22SiteRowId%22:null,%22UnionRowId%22:null,%22CertificationRowId%22:7,%22VehicleRowId%22:null,%22Comments%22:%22%22,%22ValidFrom%22:%22/Date(1597085452560)/%22,%22ValidTo%22:%22/Date(253402300799999)/%22,%22AppCustomerRowId%22:1,%22EmployeeName%22:%22Michaels,%Smith%22,%22SiteName%22:null,%22Union%22:null,%22Certification%22:%22AT&T%20Certified%22,%22DocumentTypeDescription%22:%22CertificationDocument%22,%22DocumentTypeInternalId%22:%22Certification%20Doc%22,%22VehicleNumber%22:0,%22VehicleInformation%22:null,%22ContentType%22:%22application/pdf%22,%22LastModifiedBy%22:%22zelske@company.com%22,%22LastModifiedTime%22:%22/Date(1597085452498)/%22,%22AssociatedWith%22:%22CertificationDocument%20/%20Michaels,%20Cody%20/%20AT&T%20Certified%22}
```

Comment: Is the `"%22"` being decoded as a double-quote? You may need to call a [URI decode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) on the `document` parameter, before you attempt to parse it as JSON.

Comment: Heh, reasons why json in the url are usually a bad idea.

Comment: @Taplar there is nothing wrong with passing JSON as a GET parameter, but it is better suited as a POST.

Comment: It's your opinion that there is nothing wrong with it.  It is my opinion that it introduces issues, looks ugly, and exposes the data unnecessarily to the user (who can easily go to the url and jack with it). @Mr.Polywhirl

Comment: See what exactly is in`jsonDocument`, do `console.log(typeof jsonDocument, jsonDocument)`

Comment: Please debug this - Console.log("document"); /alert(jsonDocument ); I think jsonDocument  is null or empty. The main root cause of this error is parsing empty String in JS

Comment: @VedPrakash - The document is not empty. Doing an alert() shows the entire document.